# State in redux form doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

The state doesn't change in my react form. `console.log(renderselect)` doesn't have a value - it shows `undefined`.

I tried everything but there are no changes.

```
import React from "react";
import {Field, reduxForm} from "redux-form";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {renderTextField, renderField, validate, warn, renderselect} from "../../../Components/Forms/renders"
class SyncValidationForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      errors: {},
      opencheck: "hallo"
    }
     this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }
  handleSelect = (value) => {
    this.setState({"opencheck": value.target.value});
  };
  render() {
    const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, opencheck} = this.props;
    console.log(opencheck);

    return (<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="box-body">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-3">
                <Field className="form" name="favoriteColor" label="Maak eerste een keuze" component={renderselect} options={{
                    "Geen informatie" : 'Geen informatie',
                    'Altijd open' : 'Altijd open'
                  }}
                onChange={this.handleSelect}/>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>);
  }
};

SyncValidationForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'insertstart', enableReinitialize: true,
  warn
})(SyncValidationForm);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  state => ({
    initialValues: { favoriteColor: 'Geen informatie' }
  })
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SyncValidationForm)
```

The selected box must change the state, but there are no changes. Also, in the first render, the `opencheck` in console log has no value.

Comment: You must first fetch that data in mapStateToProps function. What are you specifically trying to get from redux?

Comment: I don't see `opencheck` in props, so I would expect it to be empty. You need "mapStateToProps" for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are conflating *Redux state* (which is mapped to your React component's props in `mapStateToProps`) with the built-in *React component state* which has nothing to do with Redux. Before continuing you may wish to read these links to fully understand the difference:

- [Redux: Organizing State](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state)
- [React: State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

It's often confusing and frustrating that both of these commonly-integrated libraries both call their data source "state", but it will be important for your to understand the difference and identify which one you are using.

**If you want to use Redux to store the selected state**, your `handleSelect` function needs to dispatch the new value to the Redux store, typically by using `mapDispatchToProps` to dispatch an action, not by calling `this.setState`

**If you want to use React component state**, then you need to refer to `this.state.opencheck` in your `render()` function, not `this.props. opencheck`.